# How Can I Perform Date Comparisons in Access 2013 Query Criteria?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, date-difference

I have a date field in my table, and I'm writing a query in Access 2013 to select all items where the date is between 7-days-ago and 30-days-in-the-future.

Currently, I've added the following as "criteria" under the date field:

```
>=Today()-7 And <=Today()+30
```

But I get the following error when I try to save the query:

[image]

I've tried using DateDiff (as I have in other scenarios) but it tells me that I'm not allowed to use that type of expression as criteria.

**EDIT:** This is an Access 2013 custom web app for SharePoint 2013, and all the available functions and syntaxes appear to be different from those available in a desktop database file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confusing with the Excel function named TODAY(). In Access it is called `Date()`.

You can also use `Between..And`.

```
Between Date()-7 And Date()+30
```

**Added** In response to advice about using SharePoint:
I don't use SharePoint, but might guess that you need to specify the field explicitly:

```
fieldName >= Today()-7 And fieldName <= Today()+30
```

you might use brackets to make the statement clearer:

```
(fieldName >= Today()-7) And (fieldName <= Today()+30)
```

Comment: Your answer is actually correct, but I realize I wasn't specific enough about my application. It is a custom web app for SharePoint 2013, and the functions appear to be different from those available in a desktop database file. Also, the "Between" syntax doesn't work in a web app. Not sure why Microsoft had to make this so convoluted.